# Can you make nautilus ask for verification before deleting a file?

Tags: nautilus, delete

Can you make nautilus ask for verification before deleting a file? Now if I hit the delete key by accident I lose the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file isn't lost. It's moved to the Trash by default. You can restore it by looking in the Trash folder, selecting it, and choosing to restore the file.